# Image comes out from the div when i set property float left

Tags: css

```
.testimonial .test-name img{float:left; padding-right:15px; display:block;}
```

> above code is use to set image float left, but image comes out from the div.
>   can any one suggest me the correct property

Comment: please provide example code on http://jsfiddle.net/ or elsewhere

Comment: i have set image in a div,

Answer (score 0):

The idea of float takes the element out of the container, this is expected behaviour.

Try adding the following code

```
.testimonial {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It should keep the floated element within the container.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the HTML that goes with this CSS?

My guess is that your containing div's height is '0', because the image inside it is floated.
try using the [clearfix](http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix) trick, or prevent giving the image "float..."